# push data in not extensible array js

Tags: javascript, typescript

im trying to array.push in a for loop in my Typescript code:

```
var rows = [
  {
    id: '1',
    category: 'Snow',
    value: 'Jon',
    cheapSource: '35',
    cheapPrice: '35',
    amazonSource: '233'
  }
];
    var newRow = {
          id: productName,
          category: category,
          value: _value.toString(),
          cheapSource: merchantName,
          cheapPrice: lowPrice,
          amazonSource: suppData[k][2]
        };
        rows.push(...newRow);
export default function DataTable() {
  const { user } = useUser();
  return (
    <div>
      {user ? (
        <div
          style={{
            height: 400,
            width: '75%',
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            marginLeft: 'auto',
            marginRight: 'auto',
            marginTop: '50px',
            marginBottom: '50px'
          }}
        >
          <DataGrid
            rows={rows}
            columns={columns}
            pageSize={5}
            rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
            checkboxSelection
            onRowClick={get5CatDataNoStockCheck}
          />
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <SignIn />
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The problem im facing is that it always pushes the same row even if im changing is value just before?

PS: A simple array.push is not usable since the array is not "extensible"

Comment: Yes thats what im saying, the array is not "extensible". So i cannot simply use the array.push(newRow)

Comment: You're going to need to update your question with more code if we're to have any hope of helping. Please include the loop and where `rows` is defined

Comment: here is the main code

Comment: In your question you say "im trying to array.push in a for loop". Where is the for loop? With the code you've given so far, you should be able to just write `rows.push(newRow)`

Answer (score 0):

```
rows.push(...newRow);
```

This one line won't work to begin with. What is this trying to accomplish? - Why spread the `newRow` object.

With the code you provided `rows.push()` will work (provided the element you try to push has the correct type - you use typescript after all, so by declearing your array it will infer the type. (something like `{id: string, category: string, ...}[]` so if you now try to push something that is not of exactly that type typescript will not let you.

But in the code you showed us there is no reason why `push()` wouldn't work. From what I have got to work with I'll say that it's most likely you are trying to push the wrong type. (which causes typesript to throw an error) - and of course `rows.push(...newRow);` will throw an error regardless of typescript (it just doesn't work)

Comment: Also if `rows` will change after the component renders its value wont be updated unless it is created with `useState`. Remember that you should treat the state as immutable so when setting state you would  no longer do `rows.push` but probably do `setRows(prev=>[...prev,newRow])`

Comment: @PhantomSpooks Oh right it's also react - I totally ignored/overlooked that, there is nothing of note in the component part of the code (nothing regarding the question at least) maybe it changes maybe not - since all the data manipulation goes on outside of any component; I'm just gonna assume it's not gonna change. But if it changes that would be a whole nother discussion (which would deserve it's own question)

Answer (score 0):

you don't understand the structure of the array you created yourself, let's see the structure for the rows array, this is an array of objects:

```
var rows = [
  {
    id: '1',
    category: 'Snow',
    value: 'Jon',
    cheapSource: '35',
    cheapPrice: '35',
    amazonSource: '233'
  }
];
```

and you create a newRow variable which is an object. if you are going to add it there is no need to use the spread operator. you can just redeclare the array or you can just push into the rows array.

**Way no 1 - redeclare the array**

```
var newRow = {
    id: productName,
    category: category,
    value: _value.toString(),
    cheapSource: merchantName,
    cheapPrice: lowPrice,
    amazonSource: suppData[k][2]
};

//redeclare the array

rows = [...rows, newRow];
```

**Way no 2 - just push into the rows array**

```
rows.push(newRow)
```

Comment: since we are using typescript it would depend on what types the properties of newRow are. Typescript will throw an error if you try to push the wrong type into the array (If any one of the properties of newRow is a number typescript will throw an error) - and lowPrice really sounds like it is a number ...